# A tough inequality with a constraint?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $x_1,$ $x_2,$ $x_3,$ $x_4,$ $x_5$ be distinct positive integers such that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 100.$ Compute the maximum value of the expression
\begin{align*}
&\frac{(x_2 x_5 + 1)(x_3 x_5 + 1)(x_4 x_5 + 1)}{(x_2 - x_1)(x_3 - x_1)(x_4 - x_1)} + \frac{(x_1 x_5 + 1)(x_3 x_5 + 1)(x_4 x_5 + 1)}{(x_1 - x_2)(x_3 - x_2)(x_4 - x_2)} \\
&\quad + \frac{(x_1 x_5 + 1)(x_2 x_5 + 1)(x_4 x_5 + 1)}{(x_1 - x_3)(x_2 - x_3)(x_4 - x_3)} + \frac{(x_1 x_5 + 1)(x_2 x_5 + 1)(x_3 x_5 + 1)}{(x_1 - x_4)(x_2 - x_4)(x_3 - x_4)}.
\end{align*}

There is probably some clever insight that I haven't seen, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could do a little computer simulation getting the maximum value. Using that, you could improve the question as: "Show that the maximum value of the expression (...) is obtained for the following values for $x_i$: (...)".

Comment: I got it. It resembles the lagrange interpolation formula, which can be cleverly applied here.

Comment: Is your sum equal to $x_5^3$? If one factors it out, one obtains the sum of  the Lagrange polynomials for $x_1,...,x_4$ at the point $-1/x_5$. This sum is 1, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If the terms are factored out, the expression equals $x_5^3$ (see Helmut's comment, I checked it with Matlab).

Since we have that $x_1,$ $x_2,$ $x_3,$ $x_4,$ $x_5$ are distinct positive integers such that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 100$, the maximum value of the expression will be obtained for the smallest possible distinct integers $x_1,$ $x_2,$ $x_3,$ $x_4$. Choose $(1,2,3,4)$ for these four values, then  the maximum value of the expression is $90^3 = 729000$.

Comment: +1. BTW, treat RHS as a cubic polynomial in $x_5$. Let's call it $f(x_5)$. Notice  $f(-\frac{1}{x_i}) = -\frac{1}{x_i^3} = \left(-\frac{1}{x_i}\right)^3$ at $4 > 3$ points, $f(x)$ equals to $x^3$ as a polynomial. i.e. the terms do factored out.